# Insert via Entity Framework Core

Tags: sql, entity-framework-core

I have the following code to insert some items into a SQL database via EF Core:

```
public async Task InsertInactiveUsersAsync(IEnumerable<User> users)
{
    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        var entry = _context.Set<User>().Add(user);
        entry.State = EntityState.Added;
    }

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Is there a way to keep track the number of successful inserts and return that value?

Comment: you have written  `await _context.SaveChangesAsync();` out of the loop so all records will be inserted. if any error in one record insertion all will be roll backed.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just let the `SaveChangesAsync()` function return the number of rows affected in the database. In your case, since you're only doing inserts, this would essentially reflect the number of successful inserts.

Here's how you can modify your function to return the number of successful inserts, and I believe it should work:

```
public async Task<int> InsertInactiveUsersAsync(IEnumerable<User> users)
{
    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        var entry = _context.Set<User>().Add(user);
        entry.State = EntityState.Added;
    }

    return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

This function will now return the number of successful inserts as an integer.

One thing is that all changes you made in your DbContext (not only the ones in this method) will be saved when calling `SaveChangesAsync()`, and the number returned will reflect the total number of changes, not only the inserts made in this method.

And then if there is a failure with inserting any of the users (for example, due to a database constraint), an exception will be thrown and no users will be inserted. You might want to consider adding some error handling to this code if that's a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

```
public async Task InsertInactiveUsersAsync(IEnumerable<User> users)
{
  foreach (var user in users)
  {
     var entry = _context.Set<User>().Add(user);
     entry.State = EntityState.Added;
  }

   int NoOfRec = await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); //Identify No of Records inserted
}
```

In Above code await `await _context.SaveChangesAsync();` gives no of records Modified in Data base for `insert` and `Update`.

`await _context.SaveChangesAsync();` or `_context.SaveChanges();` `inssert`all records at once if you write it out of the loop if any error occurred Roll back the transaction. you got any exception no record got `inserted` if `Task` is completed all Records  are `inserted`.

Comment: Comment Out need explanation on `Update` or `Attach` in `EF`